# How to add notifications in django admin backend with audio

Tags: django, django-admin

I found this [blog](https://wildfish.com/blog/2014/12/09/swampdragon-real-time-django-notifications/) that addresses the task I want to accomplish which is; being able to get real time notifications in django admin (backend alerts) every time a new order in placed on an ecommerce website. However the blog is dated 2014 and the swamp django repository referenced hasn't been maintained atleast for 4 years ago.

Would you recommend I go ahead and deploy using this library because I believe alot has changed since then and I don't want to get into loops of fixing errors which have no updated and maintained documentation.  Or do you know of any other library that I could use instead to do such a task. The ultimate objective here would be to even have an audio sound/notification play everytime a new order is placed or cart has been emptied.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you already using Tornado? "swampdragon" is adding websockets to Tornado, but their code base hasn't been updated since 2015 and their URL is dead.  You may want to start with figuring out how to do websockets in whatever wsgi server you're already utilizing.

Comment: it looks like django-notifications has no web sockets so you would have to poll the provided `api/unread_list/` endpoint on regular intervals to have a similar effect.  That would probably work fine and would be far easier than implementing a web socket.